# Creating a trigger Using mySQL. The trigger is not compiling

Tags: mysql, oracle, trigger

It's giving me an error sign on ( raise application error) and won't compile at all.

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER 
`epharma`.`secure_emp` 
    BEFORE INSERT ON `employees` 
    FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN 
            if (to char(sysdate,'hh24:mi') not between'08:00'and '18:00')) then 
                raise application error ('you may insert into employee table only during business hours');
            end if
    END;
```

Comment: So something is not working? Can you fill in the blanks? It also helps if you post table definition as a create table statement so that the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: So is this Oracle or MySQL? `TO_CHAR` is an Oracle database function. `CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER` is MySQL syntax.

Comment: In addition to the other comments about mixing Oracle and MySQL syntax, you don't indicate if "not working" means it doesn't compile or if it compiles but doesn't execute.  Either way, you'd get an error message which you failed to reveal.  Also, if Oracle,  your use of to_char in the comparison is completely uncalled for and an lead to logic errors.  Your comparison should be simply 'if sysdate between trunc(sysdate)+1/24*8 and trunc(sysdate)+1/24*18)

Comment: I have edited my question thank you so much for indicating some of the problems. I hope my question is almost  clear not.

Comment: You still haven't even stated if your "error" is in creating the trigger or executing it.  When I build a script around it I get "ORA-00901: invalid CREATE command.  Take a look at your SQL Reference m.anual.  There is no "DEFINER = CURRENT_USER" syntax in CREATE TRIGGER. And you are missing an under_bar in the not-needed "TO_CHAR". I'm getting still more errors.  You need to use the 'show errors' command immediately after the failed CREATE statement to see them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the air of mystery, I guess this is what you are trying to do:

```
delimiter @
create or replace trigger irb_employees 
before insert on employees 
for each row 
    if (time(now()) not between time('08:00:00') 
                            and time('18:00:59')) 
    then 
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '75000' 
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'you may insert into employee table only during business hours';
    end if; @
delimiter ;
```

As far as I can tell, you try to use code from the product `Oracle` in the product `MySQL` (or the other way around). Though the company Oracle owns the product `MySQL` the products use different syntax. Make sure you look for information in the documentation that belongs to the product you are using.